# Валидатор субдомена в htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Привет всем!

История такая: сайт имеет не ограниченное количество субдоменов (указал * при создании субдомена). Из-за этого субдомен может быть любым (сколько угодно точек, тире в любом месте и в любом количестве и символы любого языка).

Необходимо сделать валидатор субдомена в htaccess, то я в этом полный ноль(( Прошу помочь...

Задача следующая: нужно разрешить субдомену иметь только a-Z0-9 по середине возможен знак "-" a-Z0-9 и дальше .site.com

Если условия не совпадают, то редирект на site.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(([a-Z0-9]+\-?+[a-Z0-9])|([a-Z0-9]))+.site.com$
RewriteRule http://site.com/
```

Эта борода не рабочая((

Comment: @winston3d, `-` - это специальный символ, применяемый в символьных классах, поэтому есть вероятность, что регулярка не работает вообще. Чтобы гарантированно этого избежать, надо заменить `[-]?+` на `\-?`. Но, возможно, выражение не срабатывает и не поэтому.  
upd. Точки тоже надо экранировать обратным слэшем (однако в данном примере это не играет никакой роли).
upd2. RewriteRule в данном случае перекидывает на http://site.com при **совпадении*** регулярки.

Comment: Я вот даже чутка доработал добавив "или", но  всё равно ничего не работает...

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(([a-Z0-9]+\-?+[a-Z0-9])|([a-Z0-9]))+.site.com$
RewriteRule http://site.com/